# visual studio 2010 not showing all files in a directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have approx. 105+ web files (.aspx, .css, .html, etc...) files in a folder.  I've created a 2010 web project, but for some reason, not all the files show up.  It stops at the letter p, every file after that (q* - z*) is not showing in the project.  I created a new project, but still they are not showing up.

Could there be a bug in VS 2010 that doesn't show files after some point?

Comment: Did you click the "show all files" button?

Comment: Yes I did. Otherwise I couldn't see the files up to letter p.